# How to avoid .map skipping white spaces?

Tags: javascript

Got an issue. Need to put full name from array as ID of LI element.
ATM it takes only first word for some reason.could you help?

```
const buddiesNames = ['RGX 11z Pro Buddy', 'Zedd Buddy', 'Get Carried Buddy', 'In A Bind Buddy', 'Year One Buddy'];

ulForBuddyNames.innerHTML = buddiesNames
  .map(
    (elem) =>
      `<li " class="valorantHeroBuddy"><a href="#"  onClick="showCharacterBuddy(event)" id=${elem}>  ${elem}<a/></li>`
  )
  .join('');
```

https://codepen.io/DeanWinchester88/pen/LYjmgyQ

Comment: Always put quotes around attributes.

Comment: What is the extra `"` doing after `<li`?

Comment: prolly tried smth and didn't remove :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't have spaces in an id. Try replacing them with a hyphen: `elem.replace(/\s+/, '-')`

> id's value must not contain whitespace (spaces, tabs etc.). Browsers treat non-conforming IDs that contain whitespace as if the whitespace is part of the ID. In contrast to the class attribute, which allows space-separated values, elements can only have one single ID value.

- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)

```js
var ulForBuddyNames = document.querySelector('div');
const buddiesNames = ["RGX 11z Pro Buddy", "Zedd Buddy", "Get Carried Buddy", "In A Bind Buddy", "Year One Buddy"];
ulForBuddyNames.innerHTML = buddiesNames.map(elem => `<li class="valorantHeroBuddy"><a href="#"  onClick="showCharacterBuddy(event)" id=${elem.replace(/\s+/, '-')}>  ${elem}<a/></li>`).join("");
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: thanks. well poor of me.that/s basic. how can i managed then later to compare this id with original array there element has spaces? replace again inside comparison?

Comment: Can you start by replacing spaces in `buddiesNames`? Or create a parallel array with spaces replaced.

Comment: ${elem.replace(/\s+/g, '-')}